# How to have specific css stylesheet for IE

Tags: internet-explorer

My site is gmsconnect.net, and in Google Chrome, my navigation bar seems to be fine, except for in IE, one of the icons appears below the nav bar on the bottom left-hand side. I need help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the style tag in you index.html file replace the "ul, li" style with the style below. I just reduced the margin-right and padding-right by 5px. It still looks the same but should also work on ie now.

```
ul, li {
   display: inline;
   text-decoration: none;
   margin-right:20px;
   padding-right:30px;
}
```

Also it would be good practice to move all your styles into your css file. Issues like this are easier to solve when all the css is in the same place.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! I am so glad! I am a beginner web developer so please excuse me for my novice self. Thank you! I would vote up 1,000,000 times if I had reputation on here!

Comment: Your welcome. I know, cant up vote until you have at least 10 rep. I was in the same boat not to long ago. You can accept the answer by clicking the check mark beside the question though.